# not check Token validation in Asp core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

i need to check token Validation with this :

```
 public static void AddJWTAuthnticationInjection(this IServiceCollection services,SiteSetting siteSetting)
        {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            var securityKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(siteSetting.JwtSetting.SecretKey);
            var ValidatePrameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                //Tlorance for Expire Time and Befor Time of Token .
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey),
                // I Need Check Expire Token or Not
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = siteSetting.JwtSetting.Audience,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = siteSetting.JwtSetting.Issuer

            };
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = ValidatePrameters;
        });
    }
```

and i use this middlware in project :

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                     .AllowCredentials()
                    );
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

and this is my services :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CreateRoleValidator>());
        services.Configure<SiteSetting>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SiteSetting)));
        services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
        services.AddContext(Configuration);
        services.AddLoginngBehavior();
        services.RegisterRedis(Configuration);
        services.AddMediatR();
        services.AddCors();
        services.Injection();
        **services.AddJWTAuthnticationInjection(_siteSetting);**
    }
```

but when i send the request with tokenin this controller :

```
    [Authorize]
[Pemission("مدیریت نقش ها")]
public class RoleController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Pemission("لیست نقش ها")]
    public async Task<ReturnResult<IList<Role>>> GetRoles()
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(new GetAllRoleQuery());
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Ok(result.Result);
        }
        return BadRequest(result.ErrorMessage);
    }


}
```

when i start the project it got this this service `AddJWTAuthnticationInjection` but when i send a request it not checked it .
it not checked the token Validation . and show me `UnAuthorize` . whats the problem ? how can i solve the problem ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in your code looks to jump out as misconfigured, however there are a few things that I check when I have tried to troubleshoot similar issues in the past:

**Check WWW-Authenticate Response Header**

By default asp.net will add a `WWW-Authenticate` header which can reveal what is failing. It can help you track down the issues (e.g. is the key invalid? Or the audience?). The header value will be something like `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is expired"`.

**Is the token valid?**

Copy and paste your token into [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). Is the expiry what you expect? Check issuer/audience etc.

**Check Authentication Events**

`JwtBearerOptions` has an [`Events` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.jwtbeareroptions.events?view=aspnetcore-1.1) that can be used to hook into different events and can help track down issues. Below is an example of wiring these up, adding a breakpoint or logging from within each event can be very handy.

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
  options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {
    OnChallenge = context => {
      Console.WriteLine("OnChallenge:");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
      Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed:");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnMessageReceived = context => {
      Console.WriteLine("OnMessageReceived:");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnTokenValidated = context => {
      Console.WriteLine("OnTokenValidated:");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
  };
```

**Turn Off Validation**

You have `true` for all validation events for `TokenValidationParameters`. Set these to `false` and then enable each one individually to see which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work It seems your token is invalid. Change some validation parameter values to `false` like the following code:

```
var ValidatePrameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            //Tlorance for Expire Time and Befor Time of Token .
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey),
            // I Need Check Expire Token or Not
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidAudience = siteSetting.JwtSetting.Audience,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidIssuer = siteSetting.JwtSetting.Issuer

        };
```

Then check the token's content with the `SecurityKey` on "jwt.io".
Moreover, if you're using policy-based auth, you should register the "مدیریت نقش ها" policy.